# Spring webflux security CSRF token repository

Tags: spring-security

I am using Spring webflux security. Here, csrfTokenRepository expects ServerCsrfTokenRepository and seeing error with the below sample. Is there any default implementation?

```
.csrf().csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `CookieServerCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse()`.

`CookieCsrfTokenRepository` is the servlet equivalent of `CookieServerCsrfTokenRepository`, which is why it gives an error in a WebFlux application.